# Removing number index from a string in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, string, postgresql

I'm trying to remove annoying 'indexing' from a string in all columns. Downloaded from wikipedia, index was supposed to refer to the source.

[image: Screenshot]

What I managed to find is:

```
UPDATE 
   table_name
SET 
   column_name = REPLACE(column,old_text,new_text)
WHERE 
   condition
```

but it doesn't seem to be working - I'd need to use `LIKE '%[%]%'` as old_text if 3 % would even work. 
Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for:

```
update t
set column_name = regexp_replace(column_name, '\[[0-9]+\]', '')
where column_name ~ '\ [[0-9]+\]';
```

instead of just using `replace()`.